# Listen Events in Iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I want to create an extension that records my events on a page. I am able to some operations in document like click, scroll, keyup etc.. The following code that I have

```
      document.addEventListener(DOBULE_CLICK, that.handleDoubleClickEvent);
      document.addEventListener(CLICK, that.handleClickEvent, false);
      document.addEventListener(SCROLL, that.handleScrollEvent, {passive: true});
      document.addEventListener(CHANGE, that.handleChange);
      document.addEventListener(KEY_UP , that.handleSendKey);
```

However I am not able to listen the events on iframes in web page. I know that the differences between document and iframes. I should add listeners for iframes, but I don't know how to determine the clicked area in iframe then listen it. How can I handle this problem. Thanks..

Comment: An iframe has it's own `document`. If the frame is from a different domain/origin than main page you can't access that document for security reasons. Need to clarify if this is the case or not. For a click ... that event occurs inside the frame document and doesn't bubble to the main page document either

Comment: Correction, extensions can access cross-origin iframes by declaring a content script with "all_frames": true, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). It can be either a separate content script or the main one. In both cases the iframes with matching URLs will run an instance of the specified content script. Then you can either use standard DOM messaging with parent.postMessage or use your background script to relay the messages between an iframe and the main document.